# Parse HTML from GMail with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, html-parsing

I want to build a script that will fetch an e-mail with its raw HTML, parse the HTML using the XML service and pull out various bits of data.

My problem is that when you pull through the HTML using `getRawContent()` it comes out in quoted printable format (e.g. `<table align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" height=3D"100%" width=3D"100%">`), which means the XML Service won't parse it.

Is there any way I can unencode this to get it into a more readable format? I could do a find replace on "=3D" except that a) the e-mail is too long and this times out and b) I'm guessing there might be other characters affected too.

EDIT:
I've tried this with `.getBody()` as well, but when I log the result it doesn't display any HTML tags, and if I try and search for strings that I know exist within the HTML, `match()` just returns null:

```
var htmlContent = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('myLabel').getThreads()[0].getMessages()[0].getBody();

Logger.log(htmlContent);
Logger.log(htmlContent.match('<html'));  
Logger.log(htmlContent.match('cellspacing'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use getBody() method to get the HTML content of the message.

```
var message = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[0].getMessages()[0];
Logger.log(message.getBody());
```

Comment: That doesn't include the HTML tags, though? I need the HTML structure to be able to interpret the data correctly - loop through table rows etc.

Comment: It includes all the HTML tags as well. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody()

Comment: I can't see any of this come through when I log it or search for HTML type strings. See my edit above.

Comment: I've tried your code and that does return the HTML fine for me. As soon as I replace `.getInboxThreads()[0]` with `.getUserLabelByName('myLabel').getThreads()[0]` it returns the plain text. Why would these be different?

Comment: It also works for other labels. So it seems to be this particular e-mail that is causing the issue. Can it be just the length that's causing it? These are e-mails which get clipped and I have to click on "View Entire Message" to see to the end.in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it could be rare but emails could still be sent as plain-text only. Checkout the original email message. On [Trace an email with its full headers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en) is described how to check the original message on Gmail.